How to save all changes in one transaction while using MediatR
I'm using MediatR to create an order with two types of tasks. Each task has its own command, and I would like to use a transaction to ensure that both types of tasks are saved, or none are saved.
I considered the following code, but I'm not sure if it will work:
await using var connection = await _connectionFactory
       .GetConnectionString(cancellationToken:cancellationToken)
       .ConfigureAwait(false);
await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)
       .ConfigureAwait(false);

await using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken)
       .ConfigureAwait(false);

try
{
    await _mediator.Send(new AddTaskType1Command(tasks1, transaction))
       .ConfigureAwait(false);

    await _mediator.Send(new AddTaskType2Command(tasks2, transaction))
       .ConfigureAwait(false);

    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken)
       .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    throw;
}


public record AddTaskType1Command(
    IEnumerable<TaskType1> tasks1,
    SqlTransaction Transaction) : IRequest<ErrorOr<Created>>;

public record AddTaskType2Command(
    IEnumerable<TaskType2> tasks2,
    SqlTransaction Transaction) : IRequest<ErrorOr<Created>>;

The handlers for AddTaskType1Command and AddTaskType2Command save the tasks to the database.

You are doing it in a wrong way - this atomicity should be done within the single Handle-method. Create new specific command for that, name it properly. Your current code is smelling.

@Ryan Can you provide more details on why it should be done in a single handle method? Thanks.

The fact you call two methods under single transaction means  these two operations are logically coupled. MediatR is widely used in ASPNET for Application level (ie Controllers) that consume MediatR services, so they are so called application level services that contains all the logic, and therefore they should encapsulate all the complexity related. The leaner the code of consumer - the better.

Also highly likely ConfigureAwait(false) is not needed. Highly likely connectionFactory.GetConnectionString does not need to be asyncronous - it is just fast op in memory of getting the string.
